# "Can't find model for source store" using Core Data lightweight migration and UIManagedDocument

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, database-migration

I'm trying to simply add a new property on an entity of an existing and very simple Core Data model ... and it's a nightmare.

I've created a new version of the model and added my new property in the new version.

[image: model versioning]

---

Then I tried to run (on an iPhone 6, because you know ... simulators).
No crash, but instead the beautiful following error:

```
2015-08-13 15:27:47.963 MyApp[15605:6736100] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3FF51856-ECA5-4179-AA2A-FBE5EBFDDFD2/Documents/chat.db/StoreContent/persistentStore options:{
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSPersistentStoreRemoveStoreOnCleanupKey = 1;
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x176c61600 {URL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3FF51856-ECA5-4179-AA2A-FBE5EBFDDFD2/Documents/chat.db/StoreContent/persistentStore, metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Conversation = <e884e2fd 37f94dc9 7039539a cdebcb76 8c11637f 5f5e1744 310ce768 6bdf9158>;
        ConversationBinaryMessage = <dad3bd33 9cb61f03 f2895527 fa4a0b68 998bd8f3 d8196097 a0a8ccf0 e6076053>;
        ConversationLocationMessage = <6efd4294 b70e3110 cea51fd8 89471130 823cd964 0d7cdcd9 cdbc21e6 d995de0a>;
        ConversationMessage = <11bb9596 38fa5770 d5ace0c6 063da45e 3afa77fe d5d0f012 ba94dca3 2a61fb19>;
        ConversationStickerMessage = <be1d0d79 568c2ce5 ad9654d4 51dda203 9bc28162 8e50c9df 3d8b9d04 00d12294>;
        ConversationTextMessage = <7e79e7fd 32e5ef72 b98e544b 36073978 abf202ca fc78620b d200ca02 00a33181>;
        ...
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "BB890469-0382-4C74-8D6E-4708607395D8";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store} with userInfo dictionary {
    URL = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3FF51856-ECA5-4179-AA2A-FBE5EBFDDFD2/Documents/chat.db/StoreContent/persistentStore";
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            Conversation = <e884e2fd 37f94dc9 7039539a cdebcb76 8c11637f 5f5e1744 310ce768 6bdf9158>;
            ConversationBinaryMessage = <dad3bd33 9cb61f03 f2895527 fa4a0b68 998bd8f3 d8196097 a0a8ccf0 e6076053>;
            ConversationLocationMessage = <6efd4294 b70e3110 cea51fd8 89471130 823cd964 0d7cdcd9 cdbc21e6 d995de0a>;
            ConversationMessage = <11bb9596 38fa5770 d5ace0c6 063da45e 3afa77fe d5d0f012 ba94dca3 2a61fb19>;
            ConversationStickerMessage = <be1d0d79 568c2ce5 ad9654d4 51dda203 9bc28162 8e50c9df 3d8b9d04 00d12294>;
            ConversationTextMessage = <7e79e7fd 32e5ef72 b98e544b 36073978 abf202ca fc78620b d200ca02 00a33181>;
            ...
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "BB890469-0382-4C74-8D6E-2015-08-13 15:27:47.978 MyApp[15605:6736100] CoreData: annotation: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's current model hashes are {
    Conversation = <18f45c07 25844dcb 9c392f93 5b108dd5 1aa8bcb7 ac596cda 65d09e4e e1e1e85c>;
    ConversationBinaryMessage = <dad3bd33 9cb61f03 f2895527 fa4a0b68 998bd8f3 d8196097 a0a8ccf0 e6076053>;
    ConversationLocationMessage = <6efd4294 b70e3110 cea51fd8 89471130 823cd964 0d7cdcd9 cdbc21e6 d995de0a>;
    ConversationMessage = <11bb9596 38fa5770 d5ace0c6 063da45e 3afa77fe d5d0f012 ba94dca3 2a61fb19>;
    ConversationStickerMessage = <be1d0d79 568c2ce5 ad9654d4 51dda203 9bc28162 8e50c9df 3d8b9d04 00d12294>;
    ConversationTextMessage = <7e79e7fd 32e5ef72 b98e544b 36073978 abf202ca fc78620b d200ca02 00a33181>;
}
```

So `Conversation = <e884e2fd 37f94dc9 7039539a cdebcb76 8c11637f 5f5e1744 310ce768 6bdf9158>;`

Becomes `Conversation = <18f45c07 25844dcb 9c392f93 5b108dd5 1aa8bcb7 ac596cda 65d09e4e e1e1e85c>;`

Which was to be expected.

---

Here is how I initialise my document:

```
+ (UIManagedDocument *)sharedManagedDocumentForChat {
    static UIManagedDocument *managedDocument;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSFileManager *fileManager         = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSArray       *documentDirectories = [fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                                 inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];

        if (documentDirectories.count) {
            NSURL *url = [documentDirectories[0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"chat.db"];
            managedDocument = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
            managedDocument.persistentStoreOptions = @{ NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:   @YES,
                                                        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:         @YES };
        }
    });

    return managedDocument;
}
```

---

- What am I missing here?
- Why can't Core Data find the model for the source store?

Thanks for any hint.

---

P.S: I have 2 different Core Data databases, 1 for the chat feature and 1 used for caching server responses, could this cause issues?

---

**EDIT**

Here are the two models in case it helps.
[image: models]

Comment: Hi, I have similar issue. Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @BojanBozovic, unfortunately no, I never solved this issue and had to find another way to retrieve the information that did not involve Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the original (version 1) model file in your project?

You need to make a copy every time you rev your model file.

## Apple Docs

> To perform automatic migration, Core Data has to be able to find the source and destination managed object models itself at runtime (see Core Data Must Be Able to Infer the Mapping). If you need to put your models in the locations not checked by automatic discovery, then you need to generate the inferred model and initiate the migration yourself using a migration manager (an instance of NSMigrationManager).

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the description of my question I now have `chat.xcdatamodeld` which contains the new version `chat 2.xcdatamodel` and the previous version `chat.xcdatamodel`.